# libva won't update?

Tags: vaapi

I am using 16.04, specifically GalliumOS on a chromebook.

I'm trying to upgrade my version of libva from the current 1.7 to a newer 2.0+

I've tried installing from source (which it said compiled successfully) as well as installing from a .deb I found in the repositories. In both instances after running vainfo I still see that my current version is 1.7.0

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here is my output from vainfo

`libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Bay Trail - 1.7.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD`

Here is the output at the conclusion of my build from source:

```
libva - 2.2.1.pre1 (VA-API 1.2.0)
Installation prefix .............. : /usr
Default driver path .............. : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
Extra window systems ............. : drm
Build documentation .............. : no
Build with messaging ............. : yes
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @mchid From libva version, probably xenial

Comment: Version 2.1 is available to 18.04. However, you should be able to compile using the configure flags mentioned in the following answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028521/installing-libva-and-intel-vaapi-driver?rq=1

Comment: Sorry for being so late! mchid, I tried the solution from the askubunutu page listed, unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue for me. Yes, I am on 16.04. Specifically, I am using GalliumOS for my chromebook.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` when you ran `make install`?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it again (with sudo) and I have the same results post compiling and vainfo is the same.